# Copying Range from Excel to SQL without using For loop?

Tags: sql-server, vba, sql-server-2008, excel

I want to copy a range (it can be one column like `Set DataRange = ValidSheet.Range("C22:C81")` or several column like `Set DataRange = ValidSheet.Range("C22:F81")`) from my Excel sheet to SQL-table.

However, some examples on internet suggests using `DataRange(i)` as an aray, then using `For i = 1 to 59` loop to copy every value cell by cell like:

```
For i = 1 to 59
   SQL = "INSERT INTO Table_test (Column1) VALUES (" & DataRange(i) & ")"
Next
```

Is there any direct method to copy the whole range at once without using a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a loop - but changing the strategy - as the INSERT statements are far more intensive and likely to slow down than Excels internal logic.

As such, I tend to create a loop which contains all of the values - one after another,for example:

```
For i = 1 to 59
if i = 1 then
   SQL = "INSERT INTO Table_test (Column1) VALUES (" & DataRange(i) & "),"
elseif i < 59 then
   SQL = SQL & " (" & DataRange(i) & "), "
else
   SQL = SQL & " (" & DataRange(i) & ")"
End if
Next i

   SQL.execute
```

This will create one big ugly string with all the values in, but would not take long - certainly for this amount of lines.

If you are doing any more than a couple of thousand however, you could create a temp text file of the range, and import using 'LOAD FROM FILE' - which is far quicker than these individual operators.

Comment: Why is there any need for `if-loop`? Can't only the `For-loop` itself do the same job?

Comment: @user3714330  you need the if because there is a first line and a last line and several in between

Comment: Indeed, in this case I'm building the whole picture up in one loop - so you need the first line only once, then you need to add the values each time with a comma at the end, then the last statement does not need the comma (and would cause the SQL to fall over)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I can't test it now because of some other error, but it seems a reasonable solution